# LARAVEL 5.8: ¿ Cómo podría pasar un arreglo, que contenga varias filas cual si fuera un modelo, a una vista?

Tags: array, laravel-5, registro, views, collection

He intentado pasar el arreglo que tiene varias filas de datos (entre ellos un ID y su NAME), a una colección:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
Route::get('demo', function() {
    $items = collect(
        $registro = [
          ['id'=>1, 'name'=>'martillo'],
          ['id'=>2, 'name'=>'manzana'],
          ['id'=>3, 'name'=>'mesa'],
        ]
    );
```

**return $items;** // <-- Aquí hago el return que muestra los datos como colección correctamente, coo se muestran a continuación:

[
{
"id": 1,
"name": "martillo"
},
{
"id": 2,
"name": "manzana"
},
{
"id": 3,
"name": "mesa"
}
]

**return view('models.activity.work_flow', compact('items'));** // <- aquí intento enviar la colección ($items) a la vista pero me da el error el siguiente error:

***htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given*** <- La imagen adjunta detalla el error

```
});
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: e recomendaria que revisaras los tags que pusiste, la mayoria no clarifica nada, y falta el mas importante que es el lenguaje

Comment: Gracias por la orientación ya he hecho los cambios el lenguaje es: Laravel 5.8

Comment: He mejorado la explicación del error para darme a entender mejor

Comment: He encontrado la solución después de darle vueltas al asunto: debo manejar diferente la colección $items[0]['name'] y dentro de un foreach($items as $item) quedaría así $item['name'] y no así $item->name como se manejan las colecciones que vienen de los modelos xD

Comment: Aclarando que Laravel no es un lenguaje sino un framework, el lenguaje es PHP

Comment: Es correcto @BetaM Laravel no es un lenguaje, si no un framework, el cual es bastante productivo hasta lo que he visto, por eso estoy tratando de aprender lo que se pueda, las consultas con el uso de Eloquent las estoy apoyando con el uso de colecciones para mientras aprendo bien como Eloquent resuelve las necesidades acerca de la recolección de datos en el modelo de base de datos.

Comment: @CarlosPleitez te recomiendo publiques tu solución, así otras personas con la misma duda encontrarán solución.

Comment: No sé como hacer eso soy nuevo en el foro, pero me gustaría hacerlo